# Angular2 Routing: Page doesn't navigate to my view component on clicking router-link

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have created my **`app.routes.ts`** and imported all the relevant libraries.

Thereafter, I linked all the paths to their relevant Components like this:

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AttendanceComponent} from './attendance/attendance.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';

//Route Configuration
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'attendance', component: AttendanceComponent}
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

I boostrapped my app in **`my app.module`**:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

//declarations
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from  './login/login.component';
import { AttendanceComponent } from './attendance/attendance.component';
import { routing, routes } from './app.routes';

//decorator
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      routing,
      RouterModule
    ],
  declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        AttendanceComponent
      ],
  //put services
  //providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
  //module class
}
```

On my **`app.component`**, I called my landing page

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'oosc_app',
  template: `<login></login>`
})

export class AppComponent{
}
```

The landing page is **`login.template.html`**:

```
<body class="login">
<div id="login" class="login-position">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/oosc-logo-login.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper-login">
            <input type="text" placeholder="TSC Number" class="user"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="password"/>
        </div>

        <!--<a [routerLink]="['/attendance']" class="login-button">Sign in</a>-->
        <a [routerLink]="['/attendance']"  class="login-button">Sign in</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <span>Not a member ?<a href="#">Create your account</a></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

The router link should direct the page to **`attendance.component.ts`** thereafter show the view.

The problem is while the sign in button clicks, it navigates to *localhost:3000/attendance* but doesn't sticks with the login view instead of the attendance view.

Below is my **`attendance.component.ts`**:

```
//I have separated it into headers and footers and called the templateUrl
//in a component called Content

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HeaderComponent} from '../partials/header.component';
import {FooterComponent} from '../partials/footer.component';
import {ContentComponent} from '../partials/content.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'attendance',
  //templateUrl:  `/app/attendance/attendance.template.html`
  template: `<header></header><footer></footer>`,
  providers: [HeaderComponent, ContentComponent, FooterComponent]
})

export class AttendanceComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('ngOnInit');
  }
}
```

What seems to be the problem?

How comes it's not navigating to the relevant view?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is **`router-outlet`** which is missing in your template.

```
template: `    
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <!-- not required -->
        <login></login>      
    <!-- now you don't need to use <login> tag your router will load 
          login component into router-outlet because of your default defined path-->

`
```